# Avoid an automatic new page when inputting a section after a longtable

Tags: page-breaking

When I start a new section after a longtable, I find the section begins at a new page and leaves a blank page between the longtable and the new section. But when I try just input some usual text, it just prints just at the end of the table. I want the next section following the longtable.

I find the similar answer in the [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497002/unwanted-blank-page-inserted-after-longtable), but when I want to change the size of the following:

> \begin{longtable}
> {p{3cm}<{\centering}p{8cm}<{\centering}p{3.5cm}<{\centering}}

I do not know how to do exactly. Maybe I do not understand the theory or reason of this method. Could you provide a method or explain why the above method can be used? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It will be much easier to help you if you provide us with a minimal example that shows your problem.  (Everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.)  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497

Comment: after `\section` a page break is suppressed after the heading and (in most document classes) for a couple of lines of paragraph text after the heading. Are you sure there is enough space below the table?